# C# application needs to reference remote workstation in Citrix environment

Tags: c#, winforms, network-programming, citrix

I have a C# standalone Windows Forms application. It connects to a back office system that requires the workstation name as part of the identification process. I'm using Environment.MachineName to get this. However the customer using this application will occasionally run it under a Citrix environment and, when they do, they want it to reference the remote machine name, not the machine it is installed on. I have never coded anything like this before, and am unfamiliar with Citrix (so I'm off to a flying start). How do I get the remote machine name? Any ideas hugely appreciated.

Big thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On a Citrix systems there's an Environment Variable called `CLIENTNAME` that has the name of the machine that the user is connecting to Citrix from.  It's just a regular Windows environment variable so you can use `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable` to read it.

You could do something quick and dirty like this:

```
var workstationName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CLIENTNAME") ?? Environment.MachineName;
```

For something a little more robust, a Citrix environment also has a `SESSIONNAME` variable that identifies the Citrix session.  The presence of these two variables together is probably a better test for running in a Citrix session.

So you could do something like this:

```
public bool IsCitrixSession() {
    return Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CLIENTNAME") != null
        && Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SESSIONNAME") != null;
}

public string GetWorkstationName()
{
    return IsCitrixSession() ? Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CLIENTNAME")
                             : Environment.MachineName;
}
```

Comment: Huge thanks. I believe this is read in C# using: System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CLIENTNAME", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);

Comment: Just note that the quality of the value in CLIENTNAME can be a little variable, depending on the OS of the client machine and the age of the Citrix client. This is a non-issue for Windows PC clients - those will return the machine name. This was mainly an issue for older versions of the iOS and Android receivers, so make sure your customer is using the latest versions of these receivers.

Comment: @AndrewCooper Absolutely brilliant, I really appreciate this, you have saved me hours