# Running Multiple Queries Simultaneously C# CMD - .NET 3.5

Tags: c#, session, cmd, citrix

```
*Can't use Plinq as my app targets 3.5*
```

---

I am creating an app where users have the ability to find out what the name of their current server is.

**This basically works by querying the user against every server from a list of servers, and then checking the output to see if the users name appeared. If it did, then they are connected to the server in question**

The code to find the server name looks like so (where name is the username):

```
    public static string[] get_Session(List<string> servers, string name)
    {
       string[] sessionDetails = new string[3];

        // Iterate through serverList to find the correct connection - then add this to the sessionDetails array
        string current = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < servers.Count; i++)
        {
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c QUERY SESSION " + name + " /SERVER:" + servers[i] + ".mydomain1.co.uk ")
            {
                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            };

            Process getsess = Process.Start(startInfo);
            getsess.OutputDataReceived += (x, y) => current += y.Data;
            getsess.BeginOutputReadLine();
            getsess.WaitForExit();

            if (current.Contains(name))
            {
                // Session ID
                sessionDetails[0] = current.Substring(119, 4);
                // Server Name
                sessionDetails[1] = servers[i] + ".mydomain1.co.uk";

                break;
            }
        }
        return sessionDetails;
```

This works, and seems to return the correct session details each time, but it is adding around 10 seconds on to the run time of my application.

I have looked into using a background worker class, but based on what I have read I am unsure of how I would implement something like this using that - could someone please let me know if this would be possible?

If anyone has any idea of how this could be implemented so that each server query runs in parallel with the others, I would be very grateful if you could share this with me.

Many thanks

Comment: Why don't you just get the current servers name ([`Environment.MachineName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.machinename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))?

Comment: Hi Bernd, thanks for your response.
I just tried this, and unfortunately this is returning the name of the actual client machine rather than the server which it is connected to!

Comment: a background worker would not speed things up. It would simply do your work int he background (your UI would remain responsive while you wait, that is nice though). You could multithread it if you want to go faster. The [plinq](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) framework is pretty nice for that.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Nick, will look into that now.

Comment: Ah Nick, it looks like plinq is only geared for .NET 4 and above, however I need my app to be compatible with .NET 3.5!

Comment: Are you sure `Environment.MachineName` does not contain the server name? All references point to it being so [1](http://braindrivendevelopment.com/2013/02/03/environment-maschinename-with-citrix/) and [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14250234)

Comment: Bernd, yes I can confirm that that command is returning the PC-Name (D7-084) rather than the server name (XA7-010). It is strange that those references don't match, maybe they are referring to an older version of citrix?